# Pass Header Parameter to $resource factory

Tags: angularjs, rest, header

what im trying to do is pass a parameter to the service.
that parameter would be considered as a custom header

so in my factory is this:

```
function($resource) {
    var login=$resource(constVar.get('REMOTE_USER'), {}, {
    get:{
        method: 'GET',
        isArray:false,
        headers:':myHeader'
    }
});
  return login;}
```

and my controller(security is the service) goes like this:

```
Security.get({myHeader:headers}, function(data){
        alert("success");
    }, function(){
        alert("error");
    });//headers is an object in a format {"name":"value"}
```

i just want to use that "headers" value from the controller to the service.
what im getting is like this (chrome):

[image]

i managed to create a header but it's all messed up. and the parameter i passed goes to the query parameter string.. -> i need it to be a custom header

any ideas?

Comment: Hi Joseph - were you able to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass it as an array, not as string :

```
function($resource) {
    var login=$resource(constVar.get('REMOTE_USER'), {}, {
    get:{
        method: 'GET',
        isArray:false,
        headers: {
             myHeader : 'myHeaderValue'
        }
    }
});
  return login;}
```